# Anjuta/Glade Tutorials or Better IDE?

Tags: linux, gnome, glade, anjuta

I am attempting to develop a GUI application for Tails. I'm doing the initial development on Debian 8 since development directly in Tails can be a pain.

I started out using Anjuta, but the documentation is essentially non-existent. The Anjuta website has nothing at all about how Glade is integrated or how to use it. I can't even track down documentation on how to change the main window title. The only tutorial I found has you start a project and build it using the default files that are generated for a GTKmm project.

Is there a good book or online tutorial out there for doing GUI development in Anjuta?

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to downvote a question without at least providing some explanation, so whoever you are, I would appreciate it if you would let me know what the problem is.

Comment: I think you need to crawl yourself through the GTK API manual. For your specific question for example - You would create the GUI in Glade and load this info via file or data with the GtkBuilder class. You can then access your Glade created objects and its properties. Like changing the window title.

Comment: Thank you, Florian. I am familiar with GTK and Glade. What I'm looking for is good documentation on how all of that integerates with Anjuta.

Comment: I have no experience with Anjuta, sorry. But out of curiosity, what kind of integration would you expect in this case?

Comment: Anjuta might have everything I need, but there is no way to tell because the documentation is non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not a complete answer, but it's too large to put in as a comment. I use Anjuta fairly regularly, but I share your feeling about the missing documentation (which is, by the way, not unique for Anjuta). I appreciate Anjuta (and Glade) very much, so don't take the following as criticisms on either program.

I would recommend you consider using [PyGTK for GUI creation](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is a lot more productive. You can design the GUI in Glade - exactly the same way you would do for C/C++ - and then implement the code in Python, which you can also edit and manage from Anjuta. There are plenty of code examples, for example on [the nullege code search engine](http://nullege.com).

About the work flow in Anjuta (for C/C++). It is based mainly on the Autotools system, so you should really [read up a little on make, Makefile, and related tools](http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming:tut:autotools). Though in principle Anjuta manages this, you will, sooner or later hit a problem, and [some knowledge about Autotools](http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming:tut:autotools) will help you a long way (also [this tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html) or [this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html). [This slide series is interesting](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-autotools-tutorial.pdf) - probably because it is more graphical. There are even some video tutorials, [like this one](https://www.dwheeler.com/autotools/).).

There is no real necessity to use Glade from inside Anjuta. In fact, Glade has passed a long process distancing itself from 'code generation'. It now only contains an XML generator, which can be called separately. I find the screen space left for Glade inside Anjuta insufficient for comfortable work anyway.

So, in conclusion: If you mainly need a GUI, consider Python + Gtk. If you do need C or C++, Anjuta is a great IDE, but look at Gtk Development examples [(like this one)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html). Following those, the use of Anjuta should be a lot clearer.

**EDIT**:

> Very useful answer. I have some underlying legacy code that has to be
>   C++. Is there a way to mix Python and C++ in Anjuta, or do you know of
>   any guideposts or tutorials for such?

You can open a C++ project in Anjuta - maybe even import you legacy code directly as a Makefile project. You can also add new files to your C/C++ project and create them as Python files. I've never tried to do that though, and I'm not sure how Anjuta would treat them, for example, in the Makefile(s). I don't have large projects mixing languages at the moment, but for small projects, I like 'Geany', because it doesn't get in the way. You do have to maintain the Makefiles manually.

Comment: Very useful answer. I have some underlying legacy code that has to be C++. Is there a way to mix Python and C++ in Anjuta, or do you know of any guideposts or tutorials for such?

Comment: Added a not to the original answer.

Comment: Seems like [GNOME Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder) being the latest IDE for GNOME?

Comment: I don't use the GNOME desktop and friends. I prefer the more minimalist XFCE. And lately, I'm again developing mixed apps - parts of my projects are in C, Python, and Assembler. I don't like to switch IDEs (each of which handles differently), So I still use the (also minimalist) Geany,